# Ligar led com arduino usando strings

Tags: c, arduino

> Realize código que faz com que o LED D1 fique apagado quando for enviado do PC ao arduino um dígito numérico decimal ímpar de entre {1,3,5,7,9} e aceso caso o dígito enviado for par de entre {0,2,4,6,8}.

Como é que eu faria isso?

Isso foi o que fiz até agora:

```
#define LED 4
lista[] = ['1','3','5','7','9','0','2','4','6','8']
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(pin_led, OUTPUT);
}
void loop(){
    if(lista[]=)
        if analogRead(lista[n],HIGH){
            digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    }
    else{
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja esses links para ter algumas inspirações:

- https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/read
- https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/

Tente algo assim:

```
#define LED 4

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

int par(int c) {
    return c == '0' || c == '2' || c == '4' || c == '6' || c == '8';
}

int impar(int c) {
    return c == '1' || c == '3' || c == '5' || c == '7' || c == '9';
}

void loop() {
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
        inr r = Serial.read();
        if (impar(r)) {
            digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
        } else if (par(r)) {
            digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
        }
    }
}
```

As funções `par` e `impar` são para determinar se o número recebido é par ou ímpar. Se não for nenhum dos dois (por exemplo `a`) não entrará em nenhum dos dois `if`s.

No `pinMode` deve-se definir que o pino ligado ao LED (o 4) é de saída. Como é de saída, você pode usar `digitalWrite` nele.

O número enviado pelo PC na porta serial é na verdade um caractere digital, e portanto não se deve usar `analogRead` para lê-lo, e sim `Serial.read()`.

Nota: Nunca trabalhei com arduino, então não sei se isso vai dar certo.